# Three-dimensional Plotting in Matplotlib with one line between points

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a problem dealing with 3rd dimension plot for three variables.

I have three matrices: X, Y and Z with parameters in this type:

(x_1, y_1, z_1)

(x_2, y_2, z_2)

.

(x_n, y_n, z_n)

and I can show them in separate points by scatter3D plot. blow is my code that objective[0] is x, objective[1] is y and objective[2] indicates z:

```
  from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

  ax.scatter3D([s.objectives[0] for s in algorithm.result],
        [s.objectives[1] for s in algorithm.result],
        [s.objectives[2] for s in algorithm.result])

  ax.set_xlabel('X')
  ax.set_ylabel('Y')
  ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

But, my problem is when I want to show a line between points. I want to have a line between points in direction of changing in one of the matrices, for example x.

I mean, if my goal is based on x and suppose that x is continuously increasing, i want to have a line between the point that has x_1 and the point that has x_2, then between point that has x_2 to point that has x_3 and ....

Actually this line shows, how my three parameters are changing when x is changing (when x is increased).

To do it, I used plot3D, blow is my code:

```
  ax.plot3D([s.objectives[0] for s in algorithm.result],
        [s.objectives[1] for s in algorithm.result],
        [s.objectives[2] for s in algorithm.result])
```

But in the figure I have line between each point to all other points. I mean ((n*n-1)/2) lines instead of n-1 lines.

How can i achieve my goal with mplot3d? or other ways.

Comment: Could you please post a small working version of your data? I don't see which kind of data do you have, and it is needed to answer the question